# Yii2 queryBuilder not adding where,filterwhere... and other methods such as group by on the query

Tags: yii2

I want to execute this query :

```
 $query = Actnombre::findBySql('SELECT * from bogos')->where('sagesse=:pmanu',[':pmanu'=>1]);
       echo $query->createCommand()->sql;
       Yii::$app->end();
```

But I notice that the query builder is not adding the where clause to the sql; the sql of the created command is giving

```
SELECT * from bogos
```

Why is not adding? is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are using wrong code.You are adding where condition to findBySql function, which allow only complete sql statement and restrict the where condition.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#findBySql%28%29-detail

You can check all detail on the above yii2 guide. which describes all find queries.

There are many ways to find the required data.

Comment: How can I Use then FilterWhere with createcommand? is there anyway?

Comment: If you have model Bogos for table bogos then use below  code

$query =Bogos::find()->where('sagesse=:pmanu',[':pmanu'=>1]);

 echo $query->createCommand()->sql;

 Yii::$app->end();

Answer (score 0):

Is right

This i form Yii2 Reference  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#findBySql%28%29-detail

> findBySql()
>
> Creates an yii\db\ActiveQuery instance with a given SQL statement.
>
> Note that because the SQL statement is already specified, calling
>   additional query modification methods (such as where(), order()) on
>   the created yii\db\ActiveQuery instance will have no effect. However,
>   calling with(), asArray() or indexBy() is still fine.

You should pass a complete sql Statement to the function

```
'SELECT * from bogos where sagesse=1'

$query = Actnombre::findBySql( 'SELECT * from bogos where sagesse=1');
```

Answer (score 0):

`findBySql` just execute your `'SELECT * from bogos'` request.

You can create `Bogos` [ActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html) with [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-gii-index.html) and write request like this:

```
Bogus::find()->where('sagesse=:pmanu',[':pmanu'=>1])->one();
```

or with extended [ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html) you can write beautify request:

```
Bogus::find()->sagesse(1)->one();
```